# Losing my mind trying to get a CGI script to execute instead of download using Nginix and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I cannot get a CGI script to execute itself instead of opening up a download window, do I need to add something indicating it should be inline?  I've been trying for about two days and I'm stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm trying to avoid using JS.

I created a test script and got the same result as my written script, so I don't think it's my script. Here's the test that I ran:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
now="$(date)"
echo '<html><head><title>Hello World - CGI app</title></head>'
echo '<body>'
 
echo '<h2>Hello World!</h2>'
echo "Computer name : $HOSTNAME<br/>"
echo "The current date and time : ${now}<br/>"
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

My fcgiwrap.config is as follows and is activated and running:

```
location /cgi-bin/ {
  # Disable gzip (it makes scripts feel slower since they have to complete
  # before getting gzipped)
  gzip off;

  # Set the root to /usr/lib (inside this location this means that we are
  # giving access to the files under /usr/lib/cgi-bin)
  # change
  root  /var/www;

  # Fastcgi socket
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

  # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

  # Adjust non standard parameters (SCRIPT_FILENAME)
  # change
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

My sites-available default is set up like this:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;
        root /var/www/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

 include fcgiwrap.conf;
 }
```

My fgciwrap.socket is configured:

```
[Unit]
Description=fcgiwrap Socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/fcgiwrap.socket

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

My fgciwrap.service is set up:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple CGI Server
After=nss-user-lookup.target
Requires=fcgiwrap.socket

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/fcgiwrap
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fcgiwrap ${DAEMON_OPTS} -c ${DAEMON_PROCS}
User=nginx
Group=nginx

[Install]
Also=fcgiwrap.socket
```

Comment: did you set the script to execute (`chmod+x` I think)?

Comment: sudo chmod +x -v, yes I've applied that and also just tried  chmod 755, no luck :(